# Is Hodges-Tompkins adjustment applicable for all volatility estimators?

Tags: volatility

Can the Hodges-Tompkins adjustment (S. Hodges, R. Tompkins, *The Sampling Properties of Volatility Cones* 2000,2002 JoD) be used to de-bias any estimator computed from overlapping observations? It appears that most implementations apply it under the assumption of constant volatility. Is this adjustment applicable to estimates obtained from close-close, Garman-Klass, Parkinson, etc. on overlapping observations?